# SQL statement for SQL Server that Selects entry's from a column witch contains a value sum of power of 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bit-manipulation

I wish to write an SQL statement for SQL Server that Selects entry's from a column witch contains a value sum of power of 2 (2^n), 
for instance I have TABLE xxx:

```sql
_________________________________________________________
| id | col_pow |col_pow=sum of element power of 2 (2^n) |
|----|---------|----------------------------------------|
| 1  | 11      |11  = 8+2+1   = 2^3 + 2^1 +2^0          |           
| 2  | 3       |3   = 2+1     = 2^1 + 2^0               |
| 3  | 514     |514 = 512+2   = 2^9 + 2^1               |
| 4  | 49      |49  = 32+16+1 = 2^5 + 2^4 +2^0          |
| 5  | 7       |7   = 4+2+1   = 2^2 + 2^1 +2^0          |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

EX. SELECT

1) `SELECT id TABLE xxx WHERE col_pow can_contains 4 (=2^2)`

- expected result:

```sql
| id |
|----|
| 5  |
```

2) `SELECT id TABLE xxx WHERE col_pow can_contains 2 (=2^1)`

- expected result:

```sql
| id |
|----|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
```

3) `SELECT id TABLE xxx WHERE col_pow can_contains 512(=2^9)`

- expected result:

```sql
| id |
|----|
| 3  |
```

How to write the 3 statements?

Comment: any number raise to the power of 0 is 1, how come #2 still getting results?

Comment: _Every_ counting number will match your requirement, because `2^0=1`, `2^1=2`, and every number from 3 onwards can be written as an even number (power of 2), or an odd number plus one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, using [Bitwise AND (&)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) may help here.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    id int,
    col_pow int
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
    (id, col_pow)
VALUES
    (1, 11),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 514),
    (4, 49),
    (5, 7)
```

Statement:

```
DECLARE @power int = 9
SELECT *
FROM #Data
WHERE (col_pow & POWER(2, @power)) = POWER(2, @power)
```

Result:

```
id  col_pow
3   514
```

Calculations (for `2^9`):

```
-------|----------------|-----
A      | 0010 0000 0010 | 514
B      | 0010 0000 0000 | 512
-------|----------------|-----
A & B  | 0010 0000 0000 | 512
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use integer arithmetic as well

```
declare @p int = 1;

select *
from (
    values
     (1, 11  , '= 8+2+1   = 2^3 + 2^1 +2^0')
    ,(2, 3   , '= 2+1     = 2^1 + 2^0     ')
    ,(3, 514 , '= 512+2   = 2^9 + 2^1     ')
    ,(4, 49  , '= 32+16+1 = 2^5 + 2^4 +2^0')
    ,(5, 7   , '= 4+2+1   = 2^2 + 2^1 +2^0')   
) t(id, pow, comment)
where pow % power(2, @p+1) >= power(2, @p)
```